# jsf primefaces graphicImage can not show picture

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use jsf with primefaces's graphicImage to show picture from a url,sometimes,it's work,and some time it show nothing.So i use developer tools and check it,and i found the src attribute append '?pfdrid_c=true' in the end,and if i remove it,it work.Then i try the img to replace graphicImage,it also appeared.Both of they are 400(bad request) in developer tools console,i'm sure the url is no problem,this is my code:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.urls}" var="url" emptyMessage=""
                         selection="#{myBean.selectedUrls}" rowSelectMode="checkbox"
                         style="text-align: center;" rowKey="#{url}">
                <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;"/>
                <p:column headerText="image" width="25%">
                    <p:graphicImage value="#{url}" width="64" height="64"/>
                </p:column>
                other colemns
</p:dataTable>
```

this is i use img element code,other things are the same:

```
<img alt="" src="#{url}" width="36" height="36"/>
```

what happend to it,how can i figure it out?

Comment: Normally that's a caching problem so have you tried `cache="false"`? `<p:graphicImage value="#{url}" width="64" height="64" cache="false"/>`

Comment: i have already try it,and i found it not work.